# php gd lib is installed but not working

Tags: gd, php, php-extension

On the localhost the library is working fine, when the function is called on production,php throws a fatal errer.

i checked the phpinfo() its there and it is enabled.

I tired to see if there is anything that i can add on the php.ini but i couldn't find any.
The error is thrown when i call

```
gd_info();
```

Is there anything that i can add on the php.ini file that can solve this problem, or is there another library for gd?

The error am getting is the following

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function gd_info(
```

Comment: check in your php.ini
extension=gd.so
extension=gd2.so
extension=php_gd2.so

Comment: Assuming you are linux, red eyes dev is correct. Additionally, make sure (at least one of) those files exist in your PHP extensions directory.

Comment: If you can see it in phpinfo(), with no doubt it's installed correctly. The problem is related to calling progress. gd_info should get called with some another syntax I guess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to undefined function imagefilter()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563355/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imagefilter)

Answer (score 1):

It may be a little bit late, but I hope it helps anyone.

I had the same problem when I tried to run GD over apache.
The problem was in `php.ini` path for apache. By default it is not using `php.ini` from php directory.
You need to define `PHPIniDir` in `httpd` file or place copy of `php.ini` to apache folder.

To check if it is your case you can compare output of `php --ini` from php folder and output of `phpinfo()` over apache. If it is showing different `php.ini` destinations you need to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem

although I had installed it using `apt-get install php7.0-gd` that function was undefined, so I inspected `php.ini` file in `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini`

turned out that the line for gd extension was commented!

so I removed semicolon before the line and it was working!

so crazy wasted an half an hour of mine :D